# Python input/Output explanation

Tags: python, file, input, output, readline

```
      my_file = open("text.txt", "r")
      print my_file.readline()
      print my_file.readline()
      print my_file.readline()
      my_file.close()
```

I understand that/how this prints out the first three lines of the text file, but I'm not entirely sure *why*. Since I'm printing out my_file.readline(), why doesn't it print out the first line for all three times?

Comment: Most other languages will do the same thing.  A read from a file progresses the current file position.

Comment: Note, this is standard 'sequential read'. Each consecutive read picks a new piece that follows what has been read before, and you need to 'rewind' to proper place if you want a specific piece of the file. If you want to access file like you access a variable, look at `mmap` which maps a file onto a memory address, making it accessible like a piece of RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python reads in the file and stores it in the variable `my_file` with the pointer at the start of the file or `(0, 0)`. As you start doing `readline`, python will read a line from the file and then "consume" it. In other words, the current pointer will now be waiting at the next line so when you call `readline`, it will now get the next line.

Hope that helps

The equivalent of what you are expecting would be:

```
my_file = open("text.txt", "r")
print my_file.readline()
my_file.seek(0, 0)
print my_file.readline()
my_file.seek(0, 0)
print my_file.readline()
my_file.close()
```

In the above case, the `seek(0, 0)` call resets the pointer's position to the start of the file after every `readline` so in this case, you will end up printing the first line 3 times.